# What is the view of Islam about luck?

Tags: aqidah

How is "luck" viewed in Islam?

Most of the time, we say "by luck", "it's your luck", "depends on luck", etc.  How should these words be used by a Muslim?

Is it permitted to believe on luckiness?

Comment: No such thing as luck in my view. Not sure what Islam says about it though. I assume you don't mean luck as in blessed? I assume you mean being lucky as in he won the lottery out of luck?  Or do you mean something else by luck, as in destined?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H8IhUOzScG0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as luck, things don't just happen by chance or accident.  As well as I am very sure you heard of it's synonym "fortune", to believe in such is shirk, for I am unsure of whether you heard or not of the roman "goddess"  of good luck and bad "fortuna".  So whether people know it or not, admit it or not, they are referring to roman beliefs and is shirk because there is no god but Allah, and everything that happens and will be is written.

Answer (score 0):

"Being there" with a good mood and attitude when things happen.

Having faith that God knows and sees whatever you come across with and is with you in everything you do with good intentions.