# Is there "CHANCE (LUCK)" in Islam, or that is DESTINY which is used in wrong idiom?

Tags: practical-islam, destiny

Many of times, you can hear that plenty of people use the word 'Chance' in their talking, even in their believing. For example if a person won an award in a bank or lottery, afterwards other people will tell him/her that:

> Oh, you are lucky (or actually your chance is good).

**I would like to know if there is any thing called "Chance" in Islam, if so, what is its difference with destiny which is called Qadr based on Islamic Fiqh?**

Or in truth, the correct meaning of "Chance" is "Destiny”? If so, is there any narration about it?

**Note:** The following link is related to my question, but it just answer a part of my question. And actually it doesn't answer my question especially based on destiny (Qadr) aspect.

- [What is the view of Islam about luck?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8383/what-is-the-view-of-islam-about-luck)

Comment: This might be useful:  http://sunnah.com/search/luck

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the view of Islam about luck?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8383/what-is-the-view-of-islam-about-luck)

Answer (score 3):

Only Allah knows the destiny, as only he knows the ultimate future of us, we should try our best in good way to do better in everything. As Allah gave us free will, so chances can be changed. So, it’s our freewill to change everything. And only Allah knows what is in your heart, you can deceive us but not him. So if someone get any prize, definitely he did handwork or any sacrifice for it or may has any good intention. And if we get anything without any act, like lottery, may be it can be a trial. So, we should try our best... And should take everything as a trial. Allah knows best.

Answer (score 2):

*This answer is more on the term luck and not chance.*

## The definition

I would say that we first need to define the word **luck**.
When we have defined it, then I think we can give a response to if it's a term that would exist in Islam, or is theologically accepted in Islam.

What if a person that is lucky, actually is blessed by God?

If a person plays a game and win ten times a row (which in this game is unlikely), is this luck? What do we mean with luck?

### The intention

When a Muslim says that someone is lucky, does that mean that he or she disregards the qadr, or the destiny?

I think the intention is the answer. *"Innama al'amalo bi niyyat"*

> I heard Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) saying, "**The reward of deeds depends upon the intentions and every person will get the reward according to what he has intended.** So whoever emigrated for worldly benefits or for a woman to marry, his emigration was for what he emigrated for."

.

**As Zohal replied in his answer:**

"if a person gets good grades and they say it was because of their 'good chance' they are saying that it was not Allah who blessed them with the good grades. "

I really think this is logically incorrect. You can still say that you had luck when you got your good grades **and in the same time understand that everything is from God.**

### Our language is limited

It's much easier to say "I had good luck" than to say, "I am so lucky that God has written this in my destiny, because everything that happens is from God".

For instance, we know that the earth is orbiting around the Sun and that it' rotating around its axis. But, we still say that the sun set or the sun went down. **We know that it isn't the sun that is going down. But we still say it does in our language**. Does that mean that we believe the sun is orbiting the earth? Of course not.

I think it would be just hard and weird in any language to say, "the earth now orbited or rotated to a degree which makes it possible, in our perspective to see the sun go down or set.".

Comment: Pointing out to what factually luck is, can be deemed as a beneficent matter as you nicely illustrated that. (in order to  make the issue clearer. God Bless You.

Comment: God bless you too! I edited the answer a bit, you could check it out.

Comment: Definition of luck is "by chance"

Answer (score 1):

There is no chance in Islam however destiny does exist. Everything happens by the will of Allah. Allah has written the fate of everything. This is their destiny. Your fate can change but only by the power of Du'a because it is only Allah who can change what is written for you.

By believing in 'chance' you are not believing that what happened was with the command of Allah. For example if a person gets good grades and they say it was because of their 'good chance' they are saying that it was not Allah who blessed them with the good grades.

*Remember nothing happens except by the will of Allah.*

Comment: Your logical response would be more complete if you could add at least a source for it. Anyhow, it is completely true and is a fact that you said "Your fate can change but only by the power of Du'a because it is only Allah who can change what is written for you.". Jazakallah-Khaira

Comment: Sorry I can't give a proper reference unless you want the reference to where I got things like "Everything happens only by the will of Allah" ....The best fate related reference is "Every man's fate We have fastened on his own neck: On the Day of Judgment We shall bring out for him a scroll, which he will see spread open." -Qur'an (17:13)

Comment: Uh-huh, no problem. it is nice enough as an admirable answer. Well done.

Answer (score 0):

**There is nothing like Chance in Islam.** In Islam, only that happens, what is written in our destiny. When everything is already written in book of destiny, then how can anything happened due to chance? Of course it can't.

Comment: if everything is pre-written and can't be changed, then why did prophet taught us to make DUA. hence your perception is wrong.

Comment: Brother, i believe you are not aware of the concept of destiny then. Destiny doesnt means everything is already pre-determined for everytong. its just that Allah wrote everything about us, which WE will do by our own WILL/Wish/Desire. its just that Allah knows future,so wrote it in book. its not that we are controlled by what Allah wrote for us.

Comment: @Farhan, so do you assume that it is possible for us to change our destiny by pray(Dua)?

Comment: yes. it is possible

Comment: @Farhan please incorporate that into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

When a Muslim sister or mother becomes pregnant, Allah (SWT) orders His angels to write the newborn's future; this means all things that he has to face, his total life, his happiness, sorrows, success, failures, etc.

However, our Prophet Muhammad (SAW) has said that a person can change his future (i.e. *taqdeer*) by du'a.

Comment: can we avoid these contactings, if they've to ask anything they can ask it here, that is what IslamSE for. @QaziShahid

Comment: Salaams and welcome to Islam Stack Exchange.  Please note that we are *not* a typical Internet forum. As a focussed Q&A site for answering questions about the topic of Islam, we expect answers to be comprehensive and well-written.  In addition, excessive use of greetings and niceties just adds noise to the site and are discouraged.  I would strongly recommend you check out our [tour] page for a better understanding of how the Stack Exchange model works.

Answer (score 0):

Humans don't have total free will (eg, you didn't choose when to be born, you didn't choose your length, eye/skin color, build, natural instincts (eg control your hunger etc...). But you have partial free will (if you choose to rob a bank, that is your choice). 
with your free will, god may set things in your destiny (eg, when you choose to rob the bank, your home may burn down).
It was your choice to be a burglar, but you didn't choose to have your home burn down (but had you not robbed the bank, your house wouldn't have burned) so you made yourself homeless (though you may not realize that then).

Comment: It seems to be a nice rational answer with good examples. God bless you.