# Does Islam acknowledge such a thing as bad luck? How do I get rid of bad luck?

Tags: destiny

Does Islam acknowledge bad luck? I have been faced with a string of bad happenings most of my life. And it goes against all laws of probability to be just written off like that.

I have been trying to start a business for years, but in spite of all good ideas and great implementation, all my efforts come to naught. I ran a website for years, did everything possible to make it better and also drive traffic to it (adding valuable content, reading expert blogs, and so on), but in the end I had to close it after years of efforts because I received only a trickle of traffic.

I tried many other ventures, each of them has also failed because I did not have access to funds. Recently, I had to actually refuse a lucrative opportunity that came my way, just because I did not have the money to put into the business. The customer was eager because he was sold on my product, but I could not go ahead with the deal because I had no funds. I approached several financiers, but nothing worked out, and I had to finally refuse and let my competitor eagerly grab that opportunity.

These are big things, but there are smaller things too that indicate lack of good fortune or bad qadr.

Each time I wear a new shirt, invariably something like food or a bird dropping falls on it and stains it. This happens almost without fail.

Each time I exit my home (which is on a higher floor), I miss the elevator. This happens nine times out of ten. When I am on a lower floor, I see the elevator on its way to a higher floor, and vice versa, so that I always have to cool my heels the maximum amount of time. I tried to rationalize this that I take the elevator when everyone's leaving home, therefore it's always going in the wrong direction (for me); but then this happens at all times of the day, and regardless of whether I am going up or down.

I go to the bus stop, and I see a bus leaving in front of me, and then I have to wait a long time for the next bus to arrive. This too happens the majority of times.

There are countless other such small things which I can cite here. And there are experiences that go back to my childhood, in which availability of certain conveniences was taken away from my family when I grew up and became ready for them, even though my elder brother could avail of it fully.

These may look like small things, but they are indicative of a much bigger problem: lack of good fortune, or bad qadr.

I would like to know, is there any kind dhikr or dua, or just about any kind of religious act that is both halal and legal that I can undertake to put this streak of bad luck behind me, and have Allah change my luck?

Comment: I think the thing here is how you are reflecting on "negative" situations. I think this is things that happens to all people more or less. I could also make a huge list about how often I've missed the elevator, how often I miss the bus, the train, how often it's late or how often I get stuck in traffic all the sudden or how often I get stains on my clothes, new or old. The list can be long. Does this always mean bad luck?  Do I go around and think I have bad luck, or think about these situations all the time, absolutely not

Comment: Everybody misses out on important things, that's not what the point is. The point is that the probability of such things is extremely high in my case.

Comment: Kindly also check the answer to this question:
https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17381/is-there-chance-luck-in-islam-or-that-is-destiny-which-is-used-in-wrong-idi